# split years into group of table in php

Tags: php, date

i have this code..that will generate a table with years

```
$starting_year  = 2006;
$ending_year    = date("Y");

for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
    $years[] = ''.$starting_year.'';
}


echo "<table border='1'><tr><td>";
echo implode("<td>",$years);  

echo "</td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";

for($i=0;$i<count($years);$i++) {   
    echo "<td>mydata</td>";
}
echo "</tr></table>";
```

How do i split this table of years so it will be split into groups of table with each table are group into 5 years each..

```
2016,2017
2011,2012,2013,2014,2015
2006,2007,2008,2009,2010
```

EDIT: i actually want it to look like this

```
2016    2017            
mydata  mydata          
2011    2012    2013    2014    2015
mydata  mydata  mydata  mydata  mydata
2006    2007    2008    2009    2010
mydata  mydata  mydata  mydata  mydata
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
$chunkSize = 5;
$starting_year  = 2006;
$ending_year    = date("Y");

for($starting_year; $starting_year <= $ending_year; $starting_year++) {
    $years[] = $starting_year;
}
echo '<table border="1">';
for($i = 0; $i < count($years);)
{
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.implode(',', array_slice($years, $i, $chunkSize)).'</td>';
    echo '/<tr>';
    $i += 5;
}
echo '</table>';
```

The only drawback being that your `<table>` will be reversed.

Comment: Thank you very much Bro :-) will be great if someone know how to put the year in the order like in my example

Comment: you have unclose tag in your code above btw..how do i add another row to put mydata below each of the year

Comment: I don't see which tag is unclosed. You do realise that what you ask in your edit has nothing to do with what you asked before in terms of structure? Gimme some time, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Where is your data coming from? how is it organised?